# Line break/word wrap setup for writing a book/journal

Tags: minor-mode

I've just started learning Org-Mode and have comes across the issue of unending lines while journalling. All the different minor modes for line breaking and word wrapping have me confused. I want lines to end where the screen does, and not be dependent upon me hitting return. I also want to be able to move up and down a single line, defined by the size of the window and not where a line's newline character is, because I'm constantly resizing my window. I'm using Aquamacs right now, though also use iTerm.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are looking for [visual-line-mode](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Visual-Line-Mode.html). To enable, do `M-x visual-line-mode`. To enable it globally, do `M-x global-visual-line-mode` (or in your init file, place: `(global-visual-line-mode 1)`).

From the docstring:

```
When Visual Line mode is enabled, `word-wrap' is turned on in
this buffer, and simple editing commands are redefined to act on
visual lines, not logical lines.  See Info node `Visual Line
Mode' for details.
```